# Does Craft expose PHP errors when not in devMode?

Tags: error, error-handling, logging

I'm seeing a lot of tasks hanging in Craft. Specifically, DeleteStaleTemplateCaches and GeneratePendingTransforms. I've followed the advice and instructions at https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks to no avail. The article suggests that there may be PHP errors in the PHP error log. However, I'm not seeing anything there at all.

After some digging, I see that during bootstrapping, Craft sets `error_reporting(0)` to disable PHP error reporting if the site is not in [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode). Does craft override the error handling to account for errors that could be lost due to turning off error reporting? I expect there may be some fatal errors happening within my tasks, which is causing them to hang, but they are being lost.

Any insight or documentation into how Craft handles error logging would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

After a little more digging, I found that `error_reporting(0);` does suppress certain log messages when not in devMode. This is because Craft's error handler respects the error_reporting() setting when filtering log messages. In order to reproduce, do the following:

1. Turn off devMode in Craft config
2. Set `memory_limit=1k` in your php.ini to force a fatal php error
3. Open your site in your browser and see the 500 as expected. At this point you won't see anything in `/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log` or your web server logs.
4. Edit `craft/app/bootstrap.php` and set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` around line 150, where you see `error_reporting(0);`
5. Hit your site again in your browser, and you will see a php fatal error in `/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log` regarding the out of memory issue.

Is this to be expected? Am I missing another configuration option which would not suppress fatal error messages?

Comment: Per Brad's (now deleted) answer and comment, this appears to be a bug.